# Wordpress: run php script via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I try run php script from external file on wordpress site.

Example:

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.button').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).parent('.entry_card').append('<div class="static"></div>');
  jQuery(this).parent('.entry_card').children('.static').load("insert.php");
});
```

insert.php:

```
<?php 
echo date("d.m.Y h:i:s"); //for testing

echo the_title(); //wordpress post title

if( get_field('xxx') ) { insert_cform('1'); } //some order form
else { insert_cform('2'); }
?>
```

Date is inserted correctly, but rest of the script don't working.
I'm noob in coding, sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't think insert.php has access to Wordpress-specific functions, since you didn't include those. So you can't call `the_title()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress AJAX isn't handled like that. There's nothing loading your WordPress environment so functions like `the_title()` don't exist (you're probably getting a fatal error there). Typically you create a plugin and [set up your AJAX inside](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

And then your plugin looks like this

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    echo the_title();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @vch said in a comment, if you have a simple php file that you call directly then the wordpress framework is not loaded and you cannot use wordpress functions in that file.

I think what you want to do is write a wordpress plugin which exposes an ajax action you can then call from your javascript to get the desired data.  There is [information in the codex about how to create ajax actions in plugins.](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

That said, if you call your ajax action you are not necessarily in the wordpress loop, so I'm not sure you can use `the_title()` anyway - the ajax call (as your `.load()` ajax call) is a new request so how does the server know which the current post is?  You might need to get the post id in your main page and set it as data soemwhere and send it in the ajax call.

Comment: Yeah, now I can see it myself. I'll try with plugin.